# Getting a node's neighbors but respecting the direction of the relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example purposes, I am using [this site](http://console.neo4j.org/).

Say we want to know who Morpheus knows, but we want to to retain the direction of the relationship. I want `a` to be the "from" and `b` to be the "to"

This returns all three relationships, but the direction is lost:

```
MATCH (a { name:"Morpheus" })-[]-(b:Crew) RETURN a, b
```

Further, Morpheus is always `a`... doh.

Take 2 was to let Morpheus be `a` or `b`:

```
MATCH (a:Crew)-[]-(b:Crew) WHERE a.name="Morpheus" OR b.name="Morpheus"
RETURN a, b
```

This returns twice as many rows as I expected. Apparently the `[]` relation is very free with its matches.

After some spelunking, I realized I was focusing on the wrong thing:

```
MATCH ({ name:"Morpheus" })-[r:KNOWS]-()
RETURN startnode(r) AS a, endnode(r) AS b
```

This does the trick.  3 rows back with the relationship direction respected.

I feel a little weird about not naming the nodes at all in that query. It feels like I am hacking. But then again, tying nodes together is what relationships are for. What are some other ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to combine the two approaches:

```
MATCH (knower:Crew)-[:KNOWS]->(knowee:Crew)
WHERE knower.name="Morpheus" OR knowee.name="Morpheus"
RETURN knower, knowee
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I made it harder than it had to be by not including the direction in the query.

Comment: I think I had it in my brain that Morpheus had to be on the left, as hare-brained as that sounds. I think I am about to go up a level, and that's why I'm having issues.

Comment: Indeed ;)  It definitely takes some head wrapping to see how Neo4j will match all potential permutations of a match.